# eclipse compare editor weird behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a problem with eclipse compare editor. For some weird reason it wrongly compares almost identical texts. I attach screen shot with the compare result. I have checked that behaviour in my own eclipse-rcp based application and in the eclipse compare editor inside eclipse ide.

[link to image](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/3796/comparees.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone to the Compare/Patch Preference Page and set it to ignore white space?